# Simple way of getting instagram user name from image url (php)

Tags: php, api, instagram

someone knows a simple way of getting the username (or user-id) of an Instagram user via an image URL without the official API?

example:
I have this URL https://www.instagram.com/p/B8jEbu2A6CI/

now I want to get the username (panelpromo222)

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution over the Instagram api

https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/B8jEbu2A6CI/

Comment: its not possible not using their API because the source code for that page is mainly javascript (React App)

Comment: So you ask for a solution _not_ using the API, and then post a (supposed) answer that _does_ use it?

Answer (score 0):

So then ... you not only get the user_id and fbid like this ... https://www.instagram.com/panelpromo222/?__a=1

So ... we may not necessarily ... be amused ...